# Java Day Light Saving (TimeZone/ZoneId) Support for Future Dates/Years

Tags: java, date, timezone, dst, zoneddatetime

In Java there are two options which supports day light saving functionality.
1. TimeZone
2. ZoneId

Which class is better to use? The DST will differ for each year. How does Java classes maintain those configurations for search time zone and for each year? What is the max date or year for which the DST (zoneId.getRules().isDaylightSavings(instant)) will work?

Answer (score 3):

## `java.time.ZoneId`

Use `ZoneId` & `ZoneRules`, part of the modern *java.time* classes.

Avoid `TimeZone`, part of the terrible legacy date-time classes made obsolete by the adoption of JSR 310.

## *tzdata*

Time zone information is defined in the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tz_database) stored in your JVM. Be sure to update if a zone you care about is changing.

## Zones change

> What is the max date or year for which the DST (zoneId.getRules().isDaylightSavings(instant)) will work?

Asking for the max date of future Daylight Saving Time (DST) is misguided.

The future changes in the offset used by the people of a particular region, such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) will be calculated indefinitely into the future according to the *currently known* rules.

The trick is that politicians around the world have shown a proclivity for redefining their respective time zones. This happens more often than you might think. So the rules by which we may want to plan our future scheduling are **not actually knowable**, as they are defined by capricious  humans and not by nature.

This is why you should not book future appointments as a moment. Instead use the indefinite `LocalDateTime` class with a separately stored `ZoneId`. When calculating a schedule, apply the `ZoneId` to the `LocalDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object which is a specific moment. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow, so search for more info and code examples.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).